# How can I produce a transactional RXJS stream where the state is only set when multiple calls succeed?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm currently learning rxjs in the context of Angular, but I'm having trouble combining the concepts to express the following situation correctly:

1. I have an HTTP request to an endpoint, which results in some data being returned
2. This data is in turn used to make another request, which also results in some data
3. Both of those datasets are used to set state in my application
4. However, this should be **transactional**, so if request 1 fails, i want the whole chain to fail, and if request 2 fails, i also dont want the state from 1 to be set

I currently have the following:

```js
this.httpClient
      .post('/endpoint1)
      .pipe(
        tap((firstData) => setFirstState(firstData)),
        concatMap((firstData) => this.httpClient.get('endpoint2', {body: somethingOfFirstData})),
        tap((secondData) => setSecondState(secondData))
      );
```

Which is in *some* way what i want. But ideally, i would like to have something like this:

```js
this.httpClient
      .post('/endpoint1)
      .pipe(,
        concatMap((firstData) => this.httpClient.get('endpoint2', {body: somethingOfFirstData})),
        tap(([firstData, secondData]) => setCombinedState(firstData, secondData))
      );
```

So that i dont come to the point where request1 completes, but request2 fails and i get some corrupted state.

To be clear: i **dont** want to get this data in the last `subscribe()` call, since this function resides in a service and i need to set state with the data in this service additionally to using it in the component which calls it.

Comment: Something else calling subscribe which then populates the service state seems like a poor choice in architecture, you should avoid side effects not actively produce them. The observable should return a  state that is consumed. This makes the code much easier to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Just pipe in a `map` in the second request and return the results from both the requests as an array.

```js
this.httpClient
  .post('/endpoint1')
  .pipe(
    concatMap((firstData) => this.httpClient.get('endpoint2', {body: somethingOfFirstData}).pipe(
      map((secondData) => ([firstData, secondData]))
    )),
    tap(([firstData, secondData]) => setCombinedState(firstData, secondData))
  );
```

If you have more than 2 requests, you could keep chaining them and obtain all the results using destructuring operator.

```js
this.httpClient.post('/endpoint1').pipe(
  concatMap((firstData) => this.httpClient.get('endpoint2', {body: somethingOfFirstData}).pipe(
    map((secondData) => ([firstData, secondData]))
  )),
  concatMap((combinedData) => {
    const somethingOfPreviousRequest = combinedData.slice(-1)[0];    // <-- get last element of array
    return this.httpClient.get('endpoint2', {body: somethingOfPreviousRequest}).pipe(
      map((thirdData) => ([...combinedData, thirdData]))
    )
  }),
  concatMap((combinedData) => {
    const somethingOfPreviousRequest = combinedData.slice(-1)[0]; 
    return this.httpClient.get('endpoint2', {body: somethingOfPreviousRequest}).pipe(
      map((fourthData) => ([...combinedData, fourthData]))
    )
  }),
  tap(([firstData, secondData, thirdData, fourthData]) => 
    setCombinedState(firstData, secondData, thirdData, fourthData)
  )
);
```